# How to pass in parameters in C++?

Tags: c++11

I'm debugging this function that was declared with three params, but actually passed in two, is it allowed or maybe it didn't call it directly?

```
ConfigList filter(
        const BidRequest& br,
        const ExchangeConnector* conn,
        const ConfigSet& mask = ConfigSet(true));
```

Here is the calling:

```
auto biddableConfigs = filters.filter(*auction->request, exchangeConnector);
```

I tried to print out something inside the filter, it printed out one line and one name, not two lines before it.

What is wrong?

Thanks,
Oneofkind

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments

Comment: The third parameter has a default argument that is used when no other argument is provided at the call site.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK to use it with 2 parameters only, the 3rd parameter in the function declaration is `const ConfigSet& mask = ConfigSet(true)`, which means that it has a default value that will be used when you don't send the 3rd parameter.